# How to pick the first row that has data in all columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe as follows:

col index -> 0 1 2 3

row0 stmt

row1 stmt1

row2 Name Place Animal Thing

row3 abc pqr mdfh jsdfhq

row2 is the row with actual column names and what follows is data. I want to remove all the rows before that. Currently, I'm using df.drop(df.index[0,1],inplace=True).

Need to come up with a common logic and an implementation to remove all the rows before a data like row2 . The logic I'm trying to implement is, pick the first row that has data in all columns. Remove rows preceding that.

Note : Rows before row2 may not necessarily have Nan for blank. It can be \s or \n.

Edit - This is an example dataframe. It may not be row2 where data begins all the time. It could be row5 or anywhere.

Comment: just ignore first 2 rows? `df.loc[2:]` would do

Comment: What does the CSV/File you're reading look like? This looks like something that's easier to solve when the file is read.

Comment: Sorry, I have added an edit for the question. The row with full data may not always begin at row 2. that is the challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:
It is very easy

```py
i = df['col3'].first_valid_index()
df = df[i:]
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added an edit for the question. The row with full data may not always begin at row 2. It can start anywhere. That is the challenge.

Comment: @maddy_novice I modify my answer